# Utilizando inteiros como locks em Java

Tags: java, thread

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
class classe{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer lock = 0;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                // instruções thread sem sincronia
                synchronized(lock){
                    //instruções sincronizadas
                }
                // instruções thread sem sincronia
            }
        }

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                // instruções thread sem sincronia
                synchronized(lock){
                    //instruções sincronizadas
                }
                // instruções thread sem sincronia
            }
        }

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual o funcionamento da variável `lock` como inteiro nesse trecho de código, o que acontece com ele quando entra no bloco `synchronized`.

O que preciso no meu programa é que quando a primeira thread comece a execução de uma parte de um bloco de instruções, a outra fique travada quando chegar em um bloco `synchronized` que tenha relação com o primeiro.

EDIT: Deixando mais claro o problema que tenho, preciso fazer a comunicação de várias threads que vão executar ao mesmo tempo utilizando wait() e notify(), o exemplo abaixo exemplifica melhor o problema:

```
class classe{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Integer lock1 = new Integer(0);
        Integer lock2 = new Integer(1);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                    synchronized(lock1){
                        //instruções sincronizadas
                    lock1.notify();
                    }
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                }
            }

            Thread t2 = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                    synchronized(lock1){
                        //instruções sincronizadas
                    while(condicao)
                        lock1.wait();
                    }
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                }
            }

        Thread t3 = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                    synchronized(lock2){
                        //instruções sincronizadas
                    while(condicao)
                        lock2.wait();
                    }
                    // instruções thread sem sincronia
                }
            }

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        t3.start();

        }
    }
```

Pelo meu entendimento do programa acima, enquanto a thread 1 e thread 2 estão sincronizadas, a thread 3 pode ser executada de forma independente de ambas. O pensamento está correto?

Comment: Sim, a thread 3 é "independente" porque usa um lock diferente da 1 e 2 (essas, por sua vez, usam o mesmo lock e estão sincronizadas). Mas não tem motivo pra usar Integer, poderiam ser dois Object mesmo

Comment: Não mexo muito com as primitivas wait() e notify() então não posso dar certeza que a sintaxe está correta, o código parece ok mas não estou vendo em nenhum lugar código lock2.notify() para notificar a thread 3, ela vai dormir indefinidamente. Mas acho que é melhor em vez de você descrever uma possível solução descrever o seu problema e a gente vê como ele poderia ser solucionado.

Comment: Em uma outra pergunta no caso.

Answer (score 3):

O `Integer` nesse caso não é tratado como nada em especial além de ser um objeto. Tanto que poderia ser um `Object` no lugar dele.

Praticamente qualquer objeto pode ser usado como trava para blocos `synchronized`. Você está fazendo certo, que é travar com base no mesmo objeto nos dois  blocos. A execução ocorrerá como desejado.

Se estava pensando que o `Integer` era incrementado ou algo assim, talvez estivesse procurando por [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). Mas acredito que não é para o seu caso.

Answer (score 3):

O que acontece com o `Integer` é o mesmo que acontece com qualquer objeto que você passa para o *statement* `synchronized`. De acordo com a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19), quando você faz `synchronized(expressão)`, acontece o seguinte:

- A expressão é avaliada
- se a avaliação é interrompida por algum motivo (pois ela pode ser por exemplo uma chamada de método que retorna o *lock*, e esta chamada pode dar erro), o *statement* também é interrompido
- caso contrário, se o valor da expressão for `null`, é lançado um [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)
- senão, considere que o valor da expressão é `V`. A thread que estiver executando o bloco `synchronized` dá um *lock* no [monitor associado a `V`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1)
- O bloco é executado

  - se a execução é completada, há a liberação (*unlock*) do monitor
  - se a execução é interrompida por algum motivo, também é feito o *unlock*, mas o bloco `synchronized` também é interrompido

Ou seja, não há nada de especial em usar `Integer` aí. Poderia ser inclusive um objeto qualquer (`Object lock = new Object()`) que não haveria problema. Este objeto serve somente como uma "indicação": se dois blocos usam o mesmo objeto como *lock*, isso indica que duas threads não podem executar aqueles blocos ao mesmo tempo. Não importa se este objeto é um `Integer`, `Object`, ou o que for.

---

> *Pelo meu entendimento do programa acima, enquanto a thread 1 e thread 2 estão sincronizadas, a thread 3 pode ser executada de forma independente de ambas. O pensamento está correto?*

Sim, está correto: as threads `t1` e `t2` estão sincronizadas entre si, pois ambas usam o mesmo *lock*. No caso, `t2` chama [`lock1.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) , então ela fica parada, até que `t1` chame [`lock1.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()).

Já `t3`, por usar um *lock* diferente, executa independente de `t1` e `t2` (embora no seu exemplo ela fique esperando indefinidamente, já que não há nenhuma outra thread que chame `lock2.notify()`).

De qualquer forma, não há motivo nenhum para usar `Integer`. Você poderia simplesmente usar dois `Object`'s:

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = new Object();
```

Assim você não se preocupa em criar instâncias de `Integer` com valores diferentes. Usando `Object`, você já garante que os *locks* serão diferentes.

---

Tem outro detalhe aí (não diretamente relacionado aos *locks* em si): o que acontece se `t1` chamar `notify` antes de `t2` chamar `wait`? Neste caso, `t2` não será notificada, pois ela ainda não estava parada esperando alguém notificá-la, então ela ficará esperando indefinidamente (a menos, é claro, que alguma outra thread chame `notify` ou [`notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) em `lock1`).

Para evitar esta situação, você pode chamar [`wait(timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)), passando a quantidade de milissegundos que a thread vai ficar esperando (se esse tempo se esgotar, ela para de esperar). Por exemplo, para que a thread espere no máximo por 3 segundos, use `lock1.wait(3000)`.

Comment: A dúvida em especial para utilizar o integer, é no caso de usar duas variáveis diferentes com o mesmo valor inteiro. Elas não se tornam o mesmo lock, nesse caso?

Comment: Primeiramente, tem que ser um objeto `Integer`, um `int` primitivo não serve (nem compila). O objeto tem que ser o mesmo (`lock1 == lock2` retornar `true`), não pode ser por exemplo dois inteiros com o mesmo valor. Mas coincidentemente deve funcionar porque existe um pool de `Integers` de pequeno valor para fins de economizar memória, então pode ser que o mesmo objeto possa ser reaproveitado.

Comment: Mas só testando pra saber.

Comment: @DJM_JM Assim que puder eu faço um teste e confirmo (mas hoje talvez eu não consiga)

Comment: De qualquer forma, meu palpite (sem testar) é que o @Piovezan esteja certo :-)

Comment: Editei a postagem inicial e aproveitei para colocar uma situação mais exata do que preciso.

Comment: @DJM_JM Atualizei a resposta